# How to loop if statements in python?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I want to make a loop with these code. To have X numbers of lines.

```
if line[3]>=15:
    line[3]=0
    print("line 3 is >= 15")
    if line[2]>=15:
        line[2]=0
        print("line 2 is >= 15")
        if line[1]>=15:
            line[1]=0
            print("line 1 is >= 15")
            if line[0]>=15:
                print("FFFFF")
            else:
                line[0]+=1
        else:
            line[1]+=1
    else:
        line[2]+=1
else:
    line[3]+=1
```

I want to have a loop that would make this code applicable to an X number of codes.

What I want to accomplish is like if line[4]>=15 then line[4] will be 0 then add 1 to line[3].

But I want it in a loop..so that if I want to have more than 4 lines then I will just edit how many lines I want and not anymore add additional if statements.

Comment: I think the reason you're getting downvotes is that you haven't provided enough detail in your description! If you could add more detail and explanation of what you're looking for, it would greatly ease the communication.

Comment: You need to fully explain what you're trying to do. This is very vague.

Comment: hi guys, thanks for the comments, I've already edited it, I hope it is not vague anymore.

Comment: Try writing it in pseudocode and maybe it will be clearer? Sounds like you want to test for >=15 and if so set the next elem to 0 and add 1 to the current elem for a list containing an arbitrary number of elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do but it's what I understood based on your code/comments.

```
for i in range(len(line)-1, -1, -1): 
    if line[i] >= 15:
        line[i] = 0
        if i != 0:
            print("line {} is >=15".format(i))
        else:
            print("FFFFF")
    else:
        line[i-1] +=1
```

Comment: this was the closest to what i needed. I've figure out the code I needed base on this. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but your code makes me think of a recursive sequence. If it is a recursive sequence, you should look into recursive functions in python: http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php.

From what I understand if `line=[1,36,13,17]` then we should get `line=[2, 0, 14, 0]`.

Here is the recursive function I made:

```
def test(line,n):
    if n==0: # 2) and for the last it will run here
        if line[0]>=15:
            print("FFFFF")
        else:
            line[0]+=1
        print line
        return "the end"
    else: # 1) for all calculations the program will run here
        if line[n]>=15:
            line[n]=0
            print("line " + str(n) + " is >= 15")
            return test(line,n-1)
        else:
            line[n]+=1
            return test(line,n-1)

line=[1,36,13,17]

print test(line,3)
```

Here is the result:

```
line 3 is >= 15
line 1 is >= 15
[2, 0, 14, 0]
the end
```

However I think you do not need to make any recursive sequence to do such a thing. You should follow what bouletta did.

Comment: Thanks for this! although this is not what I wanted thats is because my question were not that clear. but I've learned something from this. Thank you!